# Source of event (SCREEN_ON)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcast

I have such problem:
My application subscribed on the Intent.SCREEN_ON event, but in some cases it make wrong effect. How I can detect - SCREEN_ON has been caused by button (user has pressed the power button), or any other (alarm, incoming call, notification from whatsapp)? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

No. It's not possible.

At the heart of every broadcasts is an `Intent`. If such feat is possible then we should see the required information somewhere within them.

But if you take a look at `Intent`'s soucre, these are the only fields defined:

```
    private String mAction;
    private Uri mData;
    private String mType;
    private String mPackage;
    private ComponentName mComponent;
    private int mFlags;
    private HashSet<String> mCategories;
    private Bundle mExtras;
```

You see, among those fields there's not really one that could tell us anything about the sender.

Answer (score 0):

You can even SCREEN ON detect.

MyApp:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    registerKioskModeScreenOnReceiver();
}
private PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;
public OnScreenOnReceiver onScreenOnReceiver;




private void registerKioskModeScreenOnReceiver() {
    // register screen off receiver
    final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    onScreenOnReceiver = new OnScreenOnReceiver();
    registerReceiver(onScreenOnReceiver, filter);
}

public PowerManager.WakeLock getWakeLock() {
    if(wakeLock == null) {
        // lazy loading: first call, create wakeLock via PowerManager.
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "wakeup");
    }
    return wakeLock;
}
}
```

OnScreenOnReceiver receiver:

```
public class OnScreenOnReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private static final String PREF_KIOSK_MODE = "pref_kiosk_mode";
Listener listener;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON.equals(intent.getAction())){

        Log.e("tag", "screeneee:" + intent.getAction());
        MyApp ctx = (MyApp) context.getApplicationContext();
        // is Kiosk Mode active?
        if(isKioskModeActive(ctx)) {
            wakeUpDevice(ctx);

        }
        if(listener!=null)
            listener.onPower();

    }
}


private void wakeUpDevice(MyApp context) {
    PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = context.getWakeLock(); // get WakeLock reference via AppContext
    if (wakeLock.isHeld()) {
        wakeLock.release(); // release old wake lock
    }

    // create a new wake lock...
    wakeLock.acquire();

    // ... and release again
    wakeLock.release();
}

private boolean isKioskModeActive(final Context context) {
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    return sp.getBoolean(PREF_KIOSK_MODE, false);
}

public interface Listener {
    public void onPower();
}

public void setListener(Listener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}
}
```

manifest add:

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApp">

</application>
```

Another way to:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

public static boolean isActivityVisible() {
    return activityVisible;
}

public static void activityResumed() {
    activityVisible = true;
}

public static void activityPaused() {
    activityVisible = false;
}

private static boolean activityVisible = false;

 @Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}
}
```

main class in override metod:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    MyApp.activityResumed();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    MyApp.activityPaused();
    super.onPause();

}
```

onClick button press:

```
if(MyApp.isActivityVisible()){

    }
```

Comment: @Alexander незачто